# How to insert values in database if it set foreign key?

Tags: php

```html
<?php

if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email']))
{

$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
$sml="UPDATE  USERS SET password=$_POST[password]  where email='$email' ";
$account=mysql_query("INSERT INTO ACCOUNT(email) SELECT email from USERS WHERE email='$email' ") or die('Error:' .mysql_error());

if (mysql_query($sml,$con))
{
header('Location: ../home.html');
}

else{
die('Eror: ' . mysql_error());
}
}
else
{die('Eror: ' . mysql_error());}

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

How to insert email in account table its an foreign key for the account table.

I want to insert same email value to the account table for the other table reference.

Comment: Why FK is non-unique email address instead of row ID?

Comment: Just a note: with !empty($var) you don't need isset()

Comment: row id is an auto increment\

Answer (score 0):

You have to add user/s first. You can't add a record into Accounts table if you don't have a matching record in the parent(Users) table.

That is how foreign key constraint works. For example if you have a record in Users table with user_id = 1, you are only allowed to have records with user_id = 1 in the Accounts table. And so on...

Hint 1:

Try not to put `$_POST['key']` directly into query because that makes it vulnerable to sql injection.

Hint 2:

Use exit after header function.